# Source Code for Varargs in the Java API?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Is it possible to find source code in the Java API for Varargs (in other words, explain how the mechanism works)?

EDIT: I do have the Java source code, I was unable to find Varargs though (I looked it up online as well and didn't seem to find any info). I began to suspect that its not directly in the source code, but I'm not sure, hence my question.

Comment: What's your point? What exactly of it you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this post will be helpfull
http://boyns.blogspot.fr/2007/12/java-15-explained-varargs.html

In the end the conclusion is that compiler transforms varargs into an array in the bytecode.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I surmised that this particular functionality of Java is not exactly a class in the API, but rather an element of the language itself (and as such is in a "lower form", i.e., bytecode). I wasn't sure though, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question embodies a fallacy. The source code isn't necessarily written in Java and it isn't necessarily located in the API. In this case the function is implemented by the bytecode and the JVM.